# Merging polylines with the same class and attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, merge

I have a dataset of thousands of polylines with multiple classes and attributes in which it is possible that polylines have the same class, but different attributes.

There are some polylines that are **connected** at one end and have the same class and attributes. I am trying to merge only these specific polylines, but I have not been able to find an answer on how to merge them in QGIS.

I have found some similar questions, but all of them do not care about connectivity and suggest using "Dissolve" which merges all of the polylines with the same class and attributes. However, it is not what I am trying to achieve.

Please note the connection is important. If two polylines are not connected at one end but have the same class attributes shall not be merged.

Answer (score 3):

1. Dissolve
2. Multipart to singleparts, which will split the lines that do not touch

Comment: Thanks a lot @BERA. That is indeed the solution! You made my day!

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox